# free() in dynamic memory

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

Do I use correctly `free()` in the code below? Is it a memory leak? Is it a problem use `free()` in the main part and not in the function? If yes there is a method to free in the function and not in main?

This code copy an array in another one.

```
int *copy(const int *arr,int n);

int main(){
    int *p_arr1,*p_arr2;
    int n,i;

    printf("Insert size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    p_arr1 = calloc(n,sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Insert element %d of the array: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",p_arr1+i);
    }

    p_arr2 = copy(p_arr1,n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ",*p_arr2);
        p_arr2++;
    }

    free(p_arr1);
    free(p_arr2);

    return 0;
}

int *copy(const int *arr,int n){
    int i;
    int *new;
    new = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        new[i] += arr[i];
    }

    return new;
}
```

Comment: Just a piece of advice about something unrelated to the question. Even if it is C code, consider to avoid using C++ keywords such as `new` as variables names.  It will make your code more portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have the pointer returned by `malloc` (or in your case `calloc`) you can pass it to `free` when and wherever you want, it doesn't have to be in the same function.

However, after the loop where you print the contents of `p_arr2`, you no longer have the pointer returned by `calloc` inside the function, because you modify the pointer in the loop.

You need to use a temporary pointer variable for the loop:

```
int *p_arr2_tmp = p_arr2;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("%d ", *p_arr2_tmp);
    ++p_arr2_tmp;
}

// Now we can free the memory pointed to by the original p_arr2 pointer
free(p_arr2);
```

Or you could use simple array indexing instead:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("%d ", p_arr2[i]);
}

// The pointer p_arr2 wasn't modified, so it can be passed to free
free(p_arr2);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this loop

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d ",*p_arr2);
    p_arr2++;
}
```

the value of the pointer `p_arr2` is being changed, So using the changed pointer in a call of free results in undefined behavior.

You should write

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d ", p_arr2[i] );
}
```

Also it is unclear why you are using the compound operator += in the function instead of the operator =.

```
new[i] += arr[i];
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
int * copy( const int *arr, size_t n )
{
    int *new_arr = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( new_arr != NULL ) 
    {
        memcpy( new_arr, arr, n * sizeof( int ) );
    }

    return new_arr;
}
```

If you want to use a pointer in the loop that outputs the newly created array then it can look the following way

```
for ( const int *p = p_arr2; p != p_arr2 + n; ++p )
{
    printf( "%d ",*p );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

If the aim is to write a program that uses only pointers and excludes using of the subscript operator and indices then your program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * copy( const int *arr, size_t n )
{
    int *new_arr = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( new_arr != NULL ) 
    {
        for ( int *p = new_arr; p != new_arr + n; ++p )
        {
            *p = *arr++;
        }
    }

    return new_arr;
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n;

    printf( "Insert size of array: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    int *p_arr1 = calloc( n, sizeof( int ) );

    for ( int *p = p_arr1; p != p_arr1 + n; ++p )
    {
        printf( "Insert element %d of the array: ", ( int )( p - p_arr1 + 1 ) );
        scanf( "%d", p );
    }

    int *p_arr2 = copy( p_arr1, n );

    if ( p_arr2 != NULL )
    {
        for ( const int *p = p_arr2; p != p_arr2 + n; ++p )
        {
            printf( "%d ",*p );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( p_arr2 );
    free( p_arr1 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Insert size of array: 10
Insert element 1 of the array: 0
Insert element 2 of the array: 1
Insert element 3 of the array: 2
Insert element 4 of the array: 3
Insert element 5 of the array: 4
Insert element 6 of the array: 5
Insert element 7 of the array: 6
Insert element 8 of the array: 7
Insert element 9 of the array: 8
Insert element 10 of the array: 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```